# netty websocket + continuous PERIODIC data push

Tags: netty, server-push, executors

What would be the best way to continuously push some data periodically(say every n seconds) from a websocket server in netty?

EDIT :

I came across this post : [Best way to send continuous data in Java using Netty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781388/best-way-to-send-continuous-data-in-java-using-netty) and according to the answer,while/sleep wouldnt be very scalable, how does one schedule a job on an Executor ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. WebSocket client connects to your Netty server, handshakes and establishes a websocket connection.
2. The server registers the client's channel somewhere where it can be retrieved when there's data to send. (I use a ChannelGroup in a singleton)
3. The scheduled job fires, gets some data from somewhere, then gets a reference to the client's channel and writes the data to it.
4. The client channel's pipeline should have a few encoders in it that marshal the scheduled job supplied data into websocket frames.